# tables overlapping for some reason

Tags: html, overlapping

For some reason my `<td>`s are overlapping each other. It's not supposed to do that.
I want the center to be seperate from the left column which currently isn't.

Anyone got a clue what I did wrong? This is the website where you can see the code etc:

Comment: Can you provide your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.MiddleCenterContent` has a width of `100%`, forcing it to overlap its neighbours. A better method would be to make `defaultTable` width `100%` then just define the width of the other cells, and `.MiddleCenterContent` would fill out.

Despite this, it's better practice to use `<div>` tags for layout. There are plenty of tutorials on methods using these available on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the width of `100%` of `.MiddleCenterContent`. Do not use tables in order to structure your layout. Tables are only for tabular data. Using divs or other semanticly appropriate containers will help you to prevent such issues.

Answer (score 0):

in your css you have

```
.MiddleCenterContent {
width: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

just remove the following line

```
width: 100%;
```

which forces the center cell to be 100% large, overlapping other cells